# Does Usergrid store passwords as plaintext or encrypted?

Tags: encryption, passwords, usergrid

How does usergrid store user passwords ? 
Are they encrypted and stored or are they stored as plaintext ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the built-in /users collection, then all passwords are always encrypted using an 8-pass BCrypt encryption algorithm. The same is true for Org Admin users.

Comment: Just one little precision, Bcrypt isn't a encryption but a hashing algorithm.